# AlertDialog not closing Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button

my button code is as below and previously it closed the AlertDialog + Signed Out of Google when clicking on the continue button, but now it only signs out, the AlertDialog is still there... Anyone knows whats going on?

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    },
  );
  Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Confirm Sign Out"),
    onPressed: () {
      signOutGoogle();
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return LoginPage();
      }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      
    },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Confirmation"),
    content: Text("Are you sure you want to Sign Out?"),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

showAlertDialog invoked here ：

```
RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showAlertDialog(context);
                },
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Out',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
              )
```

Comment: Navigator.of(context).pop(); will help you in continue button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Navigator.of(context).pop();` after `signOutGoogle();` to close the dialog.

```dart
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    },
  );
  Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Confirm Sign Out"),
    onPressed: () {
      signOutGoogle();
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Pop the dialog
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return LoginPage();
      }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      
    },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Confirmation"),
    content: Text("Are you sure you want to Sign Out?"),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause an error from trying to navigate from a context you are no longer in?

Comment: it doesnt allow 2 Navigators.of(...) under onPressed

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't allow?

Comment: lol disregard my previous comment.. the last time i checked it wasnt allowing? ... thanks for the help! it works now haha